# equivalent functions in numpy

Tags: python, c, numpy

I am working on c code conversion to python using numpy .

What is numpy equivalent of following matlab functions?

```
1. mxGetNumberOfDimensions

2. mxIsDouble

3. mxGetM

4. mxCreateDoubleMatrix

5. mxGetPr

6. lookupspline
```

Comment: why unnecessarily downvoted if cant answer ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question does need some improvement.  It looks like you are converting a Matlab extension (e.g. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mxgetnumberofdimensions.html), but the question doesn't mention Matlab.  Those `mx*` functions are Matlab extension (mex) API functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assume `a` is a ndarray object:

```
a = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
```

1. mxGetNumberOfDimensions: `a.ndim`
2. mxIsDouble: `a.dtype == float`
3. mxGetM: `a.shape[0]`
4. mxCreateDoubleMatrix: `np.zeros(...)`
5. mxGetPr: `a.data` or `a.ctypes.data`
6. lookupspline: sorry, I don't know what is this, there are some spline relate functions in  `scipy.interpolate`.